# topology - limit point question

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $U \subseteq X$. I want to prove that $x \in X$ is a limit point of $U$ if

$\forall \epsilon > 0, |U \cap B_{\epsilon}(x)| = \infty \Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists y \in B_{\epsilon}(x)$ for $x \neq y \Leftrightarrow \exists x_{n} \in U$ s.t. $\displaystyle\lim x_{n} = x$ and $x_{n}$ is infinite.

My thought was to use the definition of a limit point and try to argue that $\forall \epsilon > 0, |U \cap B_{\epsilon}(x)| = \infty$ and then keep trying to go from there but I have no idea what to do. In topology I typically just stick with the definitions and come up with a logical argument but this one does not seem obvious to me at all.I would appreciate the help.

Here is the definition of limit point am using :

$x$ is a limit point of $U$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0, (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \cap U - \{x\} \neq \emptyset$

Comment: You might also tell us what definition of a limit point you are starting from.

Comment: I have added that.

Comment: @NickFreeman Your limit point definition seems to be for $\mathbb{R}$.  For an arbitrary metric space, the definition generalizes to $\forall \epsilon > 0, B_\epsilon (x) \cap U - \{x\} \neq \emptyset$

Comment: In the second statement, what is meant by $B_\epsilon(U)$?

Comment: Sorry I fixed it.

Comment: @NickFreeman I think it should be $B_\epsilon(x) \cap U$

Comment: I think you are right

Answer (score 0):

Your limit point definition can be stated as follows:
$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists x_\epsilon \neq x: x_\epsilon \in B_\epsilon(x) \cap U$$

For any $\epsilon>0$, let $\epsilon_0 = \epsilon$ and let $\epsilon_{n+1} = d(x, x_{\epsilon_n})$.  This will give you an infinite set of points in $B_\epsilon(x) \cup U$.

Comment: thanks for the help. I apologize about the second part. Maybe you will  be able to help me now that I fixed it?